# 3d graph plot dots with color

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, 3d

My goal is to plot a 3d dimensional graph of the following data:

```
(array([[-0.45940028, -1.07401008, -0.60800963],
       [-0.34535859, -0.80739745,  0.48825026],
      ...
       [-0.39106198, -0.91424521, -0.7051101 ]]), array([0, 0, 1, 1, ...
       1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]))
```

The last array symbolizes two different colors (the color doesn't matter)

How can I create a 3d graph with their associating color out of that dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it using array slicing and using the last array as colors

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

data = (np.array([[-0.45940028, -1.07401008, -0.60800963],[-0.34535859,-0.80739745,  0.48825026],[-0.14535859, -0.60739745,  0.68825026], [-0.44535859, -0.10739745,  0.28825026], [-0.64535859, -0.20739745,  0.18825026],[-0.39106198, -0.91424521, -0.7051101 ]]), np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]))

ax.scatter(data[0][:,0], data[0][:,1], data[0][:,2], zdir='z', s=80, c=data[1])
```

[image]

Comment: Just as I wanted it. A little sitenote, you forgot `plt.show()`.

Comment: I did not use it because I was using the jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

You can use mplot3d:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
xs = [1,2,3,4,5]
ys = [1,2,3,4,5]
zs = [1,2,3,4,5]
ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs=0, zdir='z', s=20, c=None, depthshade=True, *args, **kwargs)

plt.show()
```

Comment: But how the color of each dot though? I should be able to have a 4. array specifying the color of each (x,y,z) dot on the graph

Comment: The c Parameter is for the color:  A color. c can be a single color format string, or a sequence of color specifications of length N, or a sequence of N numbers to be mapped to colors using the cmap and norm specified via kwargs (see below). Note that c should not be a single numeric RGB or RGBA sequence because that is indistinguishable from an array of values to be colormapped. c can be a 2-D array in which the rows are RGB or RGBA, however, including the case of a single row to specify the same color for all points.